# Why doesn't __qualname__ work the same way in @classmethod than in metaclass

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass, class-method, magic-methods

I have implemented a minimalistic enum by writing

```
class SymbolClass(type):
    def __repr__(cls): return cls.__qualname__
class Symbol(metaclass=SymbolClass): pass

class Animal:
    class Dog(Symbol): pass
    class Cat(Symbol): pass
    class Cow(Symbol): pass
```

It works perfectly well

```
>>> {Animal.Dog: 'Wan Wan', Animal.Cat: 'Nyaa', Animal.Cow: 'Moooh'}
{Animal.Dog: 'Wan Wan', Animal.Cat: 'Nyaa', Animal.Cow: 'Moooh'}
```

However, I wondered, if I could get rid of the metaclass by using a class method instead

```
class Symbol: 
    @classmethod
    def __repr__(cls): return cls.__qualname__

class Animal:
    class Dog(Symbol): pass
    class Cat(Symbol): pass
    class Cow(Symbol): pass
```

But it doesn't work as well :

```
>>> {Animal.Dog: 'Wan Wan', Animal.Cat: 'Nyaa', Animal.Cow: 'Moooh'}
{<class '__main__.Animal.Dog'>: 'Wan Wan', <class '__main__.Animal.Cat'>: 'Nyaa', <class '__main__.Animal.Cow'>: 'Moooh'}
```

Then I wrote a little piece of test code

```
class SymbolClass(type):
    def __repr__(cls): return cls.__qualname__
    def __str__(cls): return cls.__name__

class SymbolA(metaclass=SymbolClass): pass
    
class SymbolB:
    @classmethod
    def __repr__(cls): return cls.__qualname__
    
class SymbolC:
    def __repr__(cls): return cls.__qualname__
    
class Animal:
    class Dog(SymbolA): pass
    class Cat(SymbolB): pass
    class Cow(SymbolC): pass

import sys
def printcompare(n1, l1n, l1v, n2, l2n):
    v1 = eval(n1)
    v2 = eval(n2)
    file = sys.stdout if v2==v1 else sys.stderr
    print(f'{n1:>{l1n}} = {v1+",":<{l1v+2}} {n2:>{l2n}} = {v2}', file=file, flush=True)

for name in "SymbolClass", "SymbolA", "SymbolB", "SymbolC", "Animal", "Animal.Dog", "Animal.Cat", "Animal.Cow":
    printcompare(f"{name}.__qualname__", 24, 11, f"repr({name})", 16)
```

Which provided me with the following result:

[image]

and I can't figure what make this difference. It looks like the @classmethod works as if it was a normal method...

Comment: Why are you using `eval`???

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure why you thought making `Symbol.__repr__` a `classmethod` would do anything... That won't affect the way your class object is printed, only the instances of that class.

Comment: I'm using eval (for debugging purposes), because it allows me to print both an expression and it's value. Since there is no way to print the code of an expression from the expression itself,  i'm forced to go the other way and `eval`the expression from the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can trace through what happens in the two cases to understand the differences.

A dict prints the `__repr__` of its keys and values. Since `__repr__` is a magic method, *python does not look it up on the instance*. It is critical to understand this. When calling `repr(obj)`, the binding goes like this:

```
type(obj).__repr__(obj)     # No binding happening, just calling function
```

Not

```
obj.__repr__.__get__(obj)()  # Binding of non-data function descriptor
```

You are getting the former but expecting the latter.

**Metaclass**

`type(Animal.Dog).__repr__(Animal.Dog)` is exactly equivalent to `SymbolClass.__repr__(Animal.Dog)`, which just returns the exact string `Animal.Dog.__qualname__`. There is very little ambiguity here as such. However, some confusion arises because if you ignored the fact that `__repr__` is optimized to bind on the class, you would get the same result. That is, `Animal.Dog.__repr__()` would follow MRO to the type of `Animal.Dog` and call `__repr__` with an implicit `self` of `Animal.Dog`. You would not see a difference.

**classmethod**

When you use a `classmethod`, however, you are attempting to bypass Python's optimized binding for magic methods. This is because `classmethod` relies on being bound as a descriptor first, but instead is called as a simple function.

Here is what actually happens for the first key:

```
type(Animal.Dog).__repr__(Animal.Dog)
```

This boils down to `type.__repr__(Animal.Dog)`. Notice that without the metaclass, you are now calling the default `__repr__`, not your custom one. The output should be pretty clear at this point.

If the magic method mechanism had worked as you expected, you would instead be doing `Animal.Dog.__repr__()`, which would work as expected because it would now bind `__repr__` correctly to the class through `classmethod`, and pass `Animal.Dog` as `cls`. You can try calling it this way to see what happens. In fact, even this calling convention works because the `classmethod` decorator does not blindly pass in `type(self)` to the wrapped method, but rather checks if it's the parent class object first.

Comment: Are you in some way, telling me that magic methods (or at least `__repr__`) are (is) always automatically classmethods (...which would explain why there is no difference between `SymbolB` and `SymbolC`) ?

Comment: @Camion. Not quite. Magic methods are regular functions in and of themselves. However, when the interpreter calls upon magic functionality, it accesses them as regular functions in the class and passes in `self` instead of going through the normal non data descriptor binding protocol. That binding protocol is what makes a `classmethod` work: where a normal function binds as a partial that passes in `self`, classes returns a partial with `cls` on binding.

Comment: @Camion no, they aren't automatically class methods, they simply *skip* the instance lookup during attribute resolution, put it this way, Python has a data model that states that dunder methods should belong to the class, hence, it is free to optimize the runtime to avoid looking up on the instance. It is an optimization.

Comment: I don't understand the MRO acronym (sorry, I'm no native english speaker ;-) )

Comment: @Camion, Method Resolution Order. It's the sequence of lookups that Python uses to find which method to call when `type(self)` does not define it.